# A single adjective for "quick to get working"?

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

I am trying to describe a computer code and one of its advantages- being easy to download and run, as there is little to no setup.

> We aim to facilitate scientific reproducibility and give other practitioners access to a quick-to-get-working yet performant model.

Is there a more suitable and concise adjective describing something that is easy/quick to setup/start/get working/get running? I know this could be paraphrased as for example *works right out of the box*, but out of curiosity I am looking for an adjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Turnkey** - adjective and nominalised noun https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnkey

> **Turnkey** refers to something that is ready for immediate use, generally used in the sale or supply of goods or services."